# Change the size of a checkbox with Material UI

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently having trouble changing the size of a checkbox to a custom one using Material UI. The code is the following

```
<Checkbox
    label="Check this box"
    onChange={() => dispatch(switchCompleted())}
    checked={status.showCompleted}
    style={{
      color: "#00e676",
      width: 36,
      height: 36
    }}
  />
```

I also tried using `size: 'medium'` but the size of the checkbox stays small. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 17):

Since the Checkbox item is actually an svg image, you can increase its size with `transform`.

You could style the Checkbox with an inline style like below:

```
<Checkbox
        style={{
            transform: "scale(2)",
        }}
    />
```

If you're using the [Material UI styling solution](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/), you can achieve this with a class.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    tickSize: {
        transform: "scale(1.5)",
    },
}));
```

You can then apply the above class to your Checkbox(s):

```
<Checkbox color="default" className={classes.tickSize} />
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add custom classes to it:

```js
<Checkbox
    label="Check this box"
    onChange={() => dispatch(switchCompleted())}
    checked={status.showCompleted}
    classes={{root: 'custom-checkbox-root'}}
  />
```

and then in a css file:

```css
.custom-checkbox-root .MuiSvgIcon-root{
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
```

You can check out more in [api docs](https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#css)

Comment: this answers  live demo  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-dr4mc  

Answer (score 1):

It solved my problem; just try it.

```
<Checkbox
  defaultChecked
     sx={{
     color: grey[400],
     '&.Mui-checked': {
       color: grey[500],
     },
     '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': { fontSize: 50 }
     }
   }
/>
```